# Is there a built-in function or library that converts UTC time to milliseconds in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

The UTC time is formatted like this

```
  "Tue 24 Dec 2013  5:53 AM UTC"
```

Is there a built-in function to convert it to milliseconds or I have to write my own scripts for it?

Comment: There are plenty of posts here on Stack Overflow that show you how to parse that format to either a `datetime.datetime` or a `time.time_struct` value. Have you checked out those posts first?

Comment: `datetime.strptime` will parse it to a datetime given the right format, then milliseconds should be easy

Comment: you can use this: `time.mktime(time.gmtime(time.time()))`

Comment: @FurquanKhan: How does that parse the format?

Comment: I wrote it before the edit was made.

Comment: @FurquanKhan: I made the only edit, and that edit was to add a tag.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: This is not a ISO formatted date.

Comment: Your input string doesn't even have seconds of precision...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer, using the [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) with [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) doing the parsing:

```
import time

timetup = time.strptime(inputstring, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M %p %Z')
milliseconds = time.mktime(timetup) * 1000
```

This does require that you don't set the locale in Python, leaving it at the default `C` locale, or only set it to a English locale. The `%a` and `%b` formatters only look for strings that match the configured locale, and only the `C` and English locales match the input strings.

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> inputstring = "Tue 24 Dec 2013  5:53 AM UTC"
>>> timetup = time.strptime(inputstring, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M %p %Z')
>>> time.mktime(timetup) * 1000
1387864380000.0
```

This does assume that by *milliseconds* you meant *milliseconds since the UNIX epoch*.

Comment: OK. thanks. I did a search before posting this question. What I found were solutions for parsing strings with only numbers as input. I thought I would have to convert those "Mon""Tue" or months like "Jan" "Feb" to numbers first before using the function. Thanks

Comment: Do include in your post what you found while trying to solve the problem on your own; it helps us determine if there is a duplicate post here or that you at least tried to find a solution elsewhere first.